# CryptoJS decryption with counter

Tags: javascript, aes, cryptojs

I have following python code for AES decryption using [pycryptodome](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/cipher/aes.html),  and which I verified and working.

```py
key = "password"
key = hashlib.sha256(key.encode("utf-8")).digest()
iv = b'This is an IV456' #Random.new().read(AES.block_size)
iv_int = int(binascii.hexlify(iv), 16)  # Convert the IV to a Python integer. 
ctr = Counter.new(AES.block_size * 8, initial_value=iv_int) # Create a new Counter object with IV = iv_int.
aes = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CTR, counter=ctr)
decryptData = aes.decrypt(encryptedData) # Decrypt and return the plaintext.
```

Now I need to convert this code in python using [CryptoJS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-js), I have done some coding but no idea how counter `ctr` generated.

```js
var i8a = new Uint8Array(data);
var password = "password";
var key = CryptoJS.SHA256(password);  
var input = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create(i8a);
var output =CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(input, key, { mode: CryptoJS.mode.CTR});                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
var str = output.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
```

But the `str` is always none.

**Edit:**

Based on below comment I have added `iv` and noPadding option with config but still the decrypt return empty.

```
  var iv = "112197289293498629157884805399637669174";
  //iv = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(iv); //enable this doesn't make any changes. 
  var output =CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(input, key,{ mode: CryptoJS.mode.CTR,iv:iv,padding: CryptoJS.pad.NoPadding});
```

Where I got the iv value from python side `iv_int`.

And cannot remove the `counter` from python script where I am getting error like,
`'counter' keyword parameter is required with CTR mode`

**Note:** I am sending the encrypted data from python to js through webRTC data channel.

**Edit2:**

The encrypt code in python which I actually used in python,

```
  def encrypt(row):
        key = "password"
        key = hashlib.sha256(key.encode("utf-8")).digest()
        iv = b'This is an IV456' #Random.new().read(AES.block_size)
        iv_int = int(binascii.hexlify(iv), 16) 

        ctr = Counter.new(AES.block_size * 8, initial_value=iv_int)
        cipher = AES.new(self.key, AES.MODE_CTR,counter=ctr)
        return base64.b64encode(cipher.encrypt(raw))
```

Input data for encryption

```
fp = open(filepathFull, "rb")
while (True) and not done_reading:
    data = fp.read(16384)
    encrypted = encrypt(data) 
    sendWebrtcDataChannel(encrypted)
```

Comment: You shouldn't name a variable String, as that is the object wrapper for strings. That could break a lot of code for you. It's probably not breaking the code that you posted, but it might be depending on what else you're doing.

Comment: That happens accidentally, I will correct it.

Comment: Your JavaScript code doesn't specify an IV. I expect you need to use the `iv_int` integer value (whatever that is -- I don't know the Python crypto lib well) as an `iv: ...` option alongside your `mode: ...` option. There is no corresponding `Counter` type in crypto.js, but specifying an IV and `CTR` mode should be sufficient to have crypto.js do the necessary counting. (But I guess I'm not expert on crypto.js either!) The Python `Counter` type also knows a block-size in bits, but I assume the cipher knows its own block size, so that shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: In both codes the passwords differ because of a typing error. As @apsillers already noted, the initial value of the counter must be used as IV (and passed to `decrypt`). Since the IV consists of ASCII characters, it can be parsed e.g. with the _Latin1_ encoder. The ciphertext must be passed to `decrypt` as a `CipherParams` object. Furthermore, the padding must be deactivated in the `decrypt` call. Then both codes return the same plaintext for identical ciphertext (if the same password is used).

Comment: I fixed the typing error for password, added the iv and no padding option still got empty value after decrypt. Please see the edit.

Comment: Not quite, the parsing of the IV and the correct passing of the ciphertext is still missing, see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following changes are necessary in the [CryptoJS](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/) code:

- The initial value of the counter must be used as IV. Since the IV consists of ASCII characters, it can be parsed with the Latin1 Encoder or alternatively as hex string with the Hex Encoder. The IV must be passed in `decrypt`.
- `decrypt` expects the ciphertext as `CipherParams` object.
- CryptoJS uses CBC and PKCS7 as default. Other values must be specified explicitly in `decrypt`. Since the CTR mode does not use padding, mode and padding must be specified.

The following JavaScript code is identical to the Python code:

```js
// Testdata: Ciphertext as Array
var data = [0xa6, 0x8a, 0x3c, 0x0d, 0xeb, 0x9a, 0xfc, 0x9d, 0xb1, 0x83, 0xb0, 0x47, 0x9c, 0x63, 0x65, 0x1d, 0x16, 0x6e, 0x53, 0xac, 0xf4, 0xda, 0x0f, 0xac, 0xe3, 0x56, 0xf4, 0xfe, 0x2e, 0xf5, 0x1a, 0x19, 0xd5, 0x50, 0x5f, 0x1a, 0x85, 0x34, 0x6c, 0xac, 0x47, 0xd6, 0x2c];

var i8a = new Uint8Array(data);
var password = "password";                                              
var key = CryptoJS.SHA256(password);  
var iv = CryptoJS.enc.Latin1.parse("This is an IV456");                 // Parse the IV with Latin1 encoder
//var iv = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse('5468697320697320616e204956343536');  // or with Hex encoder

var input = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create(i8a);
var output = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(
  {
    ciphertext: input                                                   // Pass the ciphertext as CipherParams object
  }, 
  key, 
  {
    iv: iv,                                                             // Pass IV 
    mode: CryptoJS.mode.CTR,                                            // Specify mode
    padding: CryptoJS.pad.NoPadding                                     // Specify padding
  });

var str = output.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
console.log(str);
var str = output.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
console.log(str);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.0.0/crypto-js.min.js"></script>
```

If in the Python code

```
encryptedData = binascii.unhexlify("a68a3c0deb9afc9db183b0479c63651d166e53acf4da0face356f4fe2ef51a19d5505f1a85346cac47d62c")
```

is used for the ciphertext, the same plaintext results.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am able to decrypt the data, but the decrypted data is not same as send data. From python `encrypt(b'testData')` and send it js through webrtc data channel after decrypte I got `var str1 = output.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);` with the content `TsqtU5sHkNf/TIME`.

Comment: What role does the posted Python `decrypt` method (for which the JavaScript code is tailored) play in this scenario? Does decryption work with the Python `decrypt` method but not with the JavaScript method? If yes, post an example (ciphertext, password and IV).

Comment: The decrypt method is actually I used to test the python section to verify en/de-cryption is working. In my actual scenario the python side do the encryption and js section do the decryption. I have added the encryption code in my question.

Comment: Have you tried to decrypt the received ciphertext with the Python `decrypt` method (which probably fails because the decryption with the JavaScript method fails)? And have you compared the ciphertext of the Python `decrypt` method with the received ciphertext?  It seems to me that the data is changed when it is sent.

Comment: Yes I have verified it with python and working,  at sender before encryption the data is like `b'\xff\xd8\xff\xfe\x00\x10Lavc58.35.100\x00\xff\xdb\x00C\x00\x08\x08\`  and after encryption it changed to `b'6Ccj285Os5ngGt0B099juChyLuG3G8sUJpAffYvR/tP25ILVwVNVAep4g23Pd` and the js-side(receiver) the data is in arraybuffer and the content of unint8array seems like `54, 67,99, 106,50, 56,53,79,115,53,110,103, 71,116,48, 66,48,57,57,106`,  And the final result at js side after decryption look like `output.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);`----> `Iby/T/xmyrflTIZeuphm1Cl7J4s9g6Muau1QRsXhhI23n8i4rAcvXsgB`

Comment: Your `encrypt` method Base64 encodes the data _after_ encryption, but the `decrypt` method does not perform Base64 decoding _before_ decryption (or did you just forget to post that?). Have you tried to Base64 decode the data on the receiver side prior to decryption.

Comment: Sorry for that, I forget to mention that I was using  Base64 encodes on python encryption code.  The test from python side(both en/de -crypt)was success when I disable the  Base64 encode and then encrypt/decrypt. So the js side I have to do Base64 decode after decryption.

Comment: Caution: Since Base64 decoding (of the ciphertext) is done **after** encryption, Base64 decoding (of the ciphertext) must be done **before** (and not after) decryption.

Comment: One more doubts, I tried with `atob` function to decode base64 encoded data, actually as my input data is of type `Uint8Array` no idea how to do the base64 decode on Uint8Array.

Comment: You can try this: In JavaScript, after the line `var input = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create(i8a);` insert the following line
`var input = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(input.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));` This converts the data from a `WordArray` into a Base64 encoded string and then with the Base64 Encoder back into a `WordArray`, where the data is Base64 decoded.

Comment: I tested it now I am able to confirm that the data after encryption(python) and data before decryption(js) is correct. But after apply decryption the result is not same. I think I am very close to result.

Comment: You may have to use the hex encoder instead of the Base64 or Utf8 encoder after decryption. That depends on your input data. Feel free, to post some test data: plaintext, password, IV, ciphertext and decrypted data.

Comment: I posted in pastebin here https://pastebin.com/xhFtp02U

Comment: Thanks, the problem resolved now I am able decrypt the data correctly, I have to use `var str2 = output.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);`